# sas substring up to first space

Tags: regex, string, sas

I am analyzing data. I need to extract everything from these strings before the first space. How can I extract the substring of everything up to the first space. I am using SAS and have used PRXMATCH but not familiar with doing this. Thanks!

```
0518Audible adbl.co/bill NJ              01
06257-ELEVEN CHICAGO IL                  Purchase $33.30 Cash Back $10.00
0625#03345 JEWEL CHICAGO IL                         Purchase $58.58 Cash Back $20.00                                             00
```

So in my output I need:

```
0518Audible
06257-ELEVEN
0625#03345
```

I then need to extract only the first numbers so I get:

```
0518
06257
0625
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks much

Did not work:

```
TXN_DESCRIPTION_2=prxmatch('/^\d+/', TXN_DESCRIPTION_1);
```

Comment: You don't need RegEx at all... raw SAS code: `scan(data,1," ")` for up to first space; `substr(data,1,notdigit(data)-1)` for the beginning numeric portion.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew The linked question is not a full duplicate and only answers the second half of the question (and even in a different language, which may answer the "regex" part but not how to apply it in SAS, which the OP may need).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use prxchange.

```
data have;
length string $500.;
string="0518Audible adbl.co/bill NJ              01";output;
string="06257-ELEVEN CHICAGO IL                  Purchase $33.30 Cash Back $10.00";output;;
string="0625#03345 JEWEL CHICAGO IL                         Purchase $58.58 Cash Back $20.00                                             00";output;
run;

data want;
   set have;
   string1=prxchange('s/(^\S+).*/$1/',-1,string);
   string2=prxchange('s/(^\d+).*/$1/',-1,string);
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

SAS has some simple string manipulation methods that can be used also, if desired:

```
data have;
length str $500.;
str="0518Audible adbl.co/bill NJ       01";output;
str="06257-ELEVEN CHICAGO IL           Purchase $33.30 Cash Back $10.00";output;
str="0625#03345 JEWEL CHICAGO IL       Purchase $58.58 Cash Back $20.00";output;
run;

data want;
   set have;
   str1=scan(str,1," ");
   str2=substr(str,1,notdigit(str)-1);
run;
```

Comment: may be you mean str instead of string in str2=substr(string,1,notdigit(str)-1);

Comment: Thanks Kiran - fixed.